# ExtJS Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS / PHP app that im working on and i keep running into the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

The lines that im working with are as follows;

```
parentPanel = Ext.getCmp('<?php echo $thename; ?>_<?php echo $formDetails ?>');
parentPanel.add(theGridPanel);
parentPanel.doLayout();
```

Im not exactly whats going on.

Any help would be awesome

Comment: check @Shahbaz's answer. `Ext.getCmp` has one parameter - string, the id of the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ext.getCmp() is meant to find an element in the DOM by its ID.

So just make sure you are passing the right id and in the right case to Ext.getCmp().

If you need, please check the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.html#method-getCmp)

**EDIT**

Extending my answer as I agree with the point mentioned by @scebotari66 in the comments.

Ext.getCmp() is meant to find extjs components only and not any html element in the DOM.

So that means Ext.getCmp() is **not equal** to document.getElementById()

What I mentioned 'find an element in the DOM' is just for easier understanding of the task performed by the command getCmp() whereas in actual it fetches the component with the given ID from the Ext.ComponentManager and not from the DOM

Comment: @Shahbaz You should edit your answer. Ext.getCmp does not look for a element in DOM, it looks for a component in the Ext.ComponentManager, which is a totally different thing

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript tries to call `.add()` on an `undefined`. To be more exact. this line:

`Ext.getCmp('<?php echo $thename; ?>_<?php echo $formDetails ?>');`

returns `undefined`.

So make sure you correct your query.